# AsyncTask.doInBackground - abstract method not implemented error in Android Scala project

Tags: android, scala, proguard

Can anyone give me any clues on how to debug the following.

I have a mixed java / scala android project that I'm working on in Intellij and I process it through Proguard as part of run config.

When I run the app I get the error:

```
07-24 12:36:35.879  21731-21779/com.ovaphone E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
        at android.os.AsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

I'm guessing it's caused by Proguard stripping out too much.

I do have one class that extends AsyncTask, and I know this class is definitely the culprit as when I comment out its use the problem disappears.

My AsyncTask is:

```
object CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup {
  class Payload(var mainActivity: MainActivity) {
    var isConnected: java.lang.Boolean = false
  }
```

}

class CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup extends AsyncTask[CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup.Payload, Void, CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup.Payload] {

```
 override def doInBackground(params: Payload*): Payload = {
      val payload = params(0)
      <checks the network status and sets Payload.isConnected>
      payload
  }

 override def onPostExecute(payload: Payload) {
      <updates network status on screen of MainActivity>
  }
```

}

And it's called in the MainActivity by:

```
 new CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup().execute(new CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup.Payload(this))
```

I've tried adding both:

```
-keep class * extends android.os.AsyncTask {
  *;
}
```

and

```
-keep public class com.mypackage.MyClass extends android.os.AsyncTask
```

to the proguard config file but neither make a difference.

Should those '-keep' statements be sufficient?

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to proceed?

**Edit**

Following Eric's suggestion, running javap on the compiled class gives the following output:

```
public class com.ovaphone.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup extends android.os.AsyncTask<com.ovaphone.Payload, java.lang.Void, com.ovaphone.Payload> {
  public com.ovaphone.Payload doInBackground(scala.collection.Seq<com.ovaphone.Payload>);
  public void onPostExecute(com.ovaphone.Payload);
  public com.ovaphone.Payload doInBackground(com.ovaphone.Payload[]);
  public void onPostExecute(java.lang.Object);
  public com.ovaphone.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup();
```

}

Running dexdump on the process apk shows that doInBackground is missing (but onPastExecute is not).

To investigate if problem was being caused by the interaction between Proguard and Scala, I wrote java version of the code (I've just noticed it's slightly different, in that Payload is an inner class of CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup, but I don't think that is significant). The java version works fine! Here's the javap output:

```
class com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup extends android.os.AsyncTask<com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup$Payload, java.lang.Void, com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup$Payload> {
  com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup();
  protected com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup$Payload doInBackground(com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup$Payload...);
  protected void onPostExecute(com.mysimplet.CheckNetworkStatusOnStartup$Payload);
  protected void onPostExecute(java.lang.Object);
  protected java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.Object...);
}
```

Notice the difference between the method definitions for doInBackground:

```
Scala: public com.ovaphone.Payload doInBackground(scala.collection.Seq<com.ovaphone.Payload>);
```

vs

```
Java: protected com.ovpahone.Payload doInBackground(com.ovaphone.Payload...);
```

So, Scala has transformed the varargs into a Seq. Maybe that's confusing Proguard? Anyone any ideas?

As a workaround, I've included the java version of the class in my project, but it would be nice to get the Scala version working soon.

Comment: What's your AsyncTask look like, can you post the code?

Comment: sure - it's a bit lengthy, you want to see it all or just the definition?

Comment: I've added a summarised version, hopefully that's sufficient. I think the whole code would have polluted the thread. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: No problem, I think you need to Override doInBackground like you do with onPostExecute.

Comment: Good spot! However, just added it in and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'll update the post.

Comment: Also, just noticed that I declared doInBackground and onPostExecute as protected, I'll make them public.

Comment: When I looked up the error it seems to occur when different versions of the SDK are being mixed together.  I haven't used proguard extensively, but it seems like you should be fine with it.  I think protected is correct for both of those functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57929/discussion-between-damian-helme-and-raz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that ProGuard gets a suitable Android runtime (android.jar). Depending on your build process, it is added automatically (e.g. Android Ant, Gradle, Eclipse) or you have to add it yourself with the option `-libraryjars` (e.g. custom build).

Note that you can see which configuration ProGuard is applying with

```
-printconfiguration config.txt
```

You should then check the `-injars` and `-libraryjars` options.

Without the proper runtime jar, ProGuard generally prints out many warnings and by default refuses to continue. It needs the runtime classes to analyze the structure of the application. In this case, for instance, it needs to know the runtime interface methods, so it doesn't remove them from your implementation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't explicitly specified android.jar in the config file, but using '-printconfiguration config.txt', I see that the build process is automatically adding in the correct file (-libraryjars /Applications/android-sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar).

Comment: You can use `javap` to check if the compiled class files of your implementations of AsyncTask have implementations of doInBackground with the proper signature, as specified in the runtime. You can use `dexdump` to check if that is still the case in the processed apk file.

Comment: The output is useful indeed: the Java version has the required implementation `java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.Object...)`, but the Scala version doesn't. Note the exact signature; other `doInBackground` methods don't count. The problem exists before ProGuard processes the code. You should look into getting the right signatures from the Scala compiler.

Comment: @DamianHelme did you find any solution other than writing java version of your AsyncTask?

Comment: @aga sorry, time pressure took my attention elsewhere, and I ended up leaving the AsyncTask in java. I created this thread on Scala-user: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-user/asynctask/scala-user/1nc8VYXrW0U/gmIuXyUYLRIJ and the discussion progressed a little.

Answer (score 2):

This may help.

http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/12/scala-and-android-asynctask-implementation-problem.html

Signature issue I'd hazard a guess.

Just had the same problem myself, changing the signature resolved the issue for me.

Comment: As for Scala 2.11, it seems that we also have to change the signature of return type. That means we have to use `doInBackground(p1: AnyRef*): AnyRef`, instead of `doInBackground(p1: AnyRef*): String`