# Executing task asynchronously from a timer freezes UI when resuming from background

Tags: android, scala, android-asynctask

The app i am developing is displaying schedules for local trams. The data is fetched from a website and should be refreshed every 30 seconds. For executing the fetch in background i reimplemented AsyncTask in a way more suited for scala.

Excerpt from `class RichFuture[T](future: Future[U])` which is enriching `Future` via an implicit conversion:

```
def mapUI[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit activity: Activity, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[U] = {
  val promise = Promise[U]
  future andThen {
    case Success(value) ⇒
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = {
          try {
            promise.success(func(value))
          } catch {
            case t: Throwable ⇒ promise.failure(t)
          }
        }
      })
    case Failure(fail) ⇒
      promise.failure(fail)
  }
  promise.future
}
```

This essentially replaces AsyncTask [which does not work in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934022/asynctask-doinbackground-abstract-method-not-implemented-error-in-android-scal). The full class can be seen at [github](https://github.com/Richard-W/jenastop/blob/master/src/main/scala/RichFuture.scala). I do not think it's relevant though.

The fetch function functions looks like this:

```
def fetchSchedule(): Unit = {
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
  Schedule.fetch(station) mapUI { schedules ⇒
    Log.w("Jenastop", "Schedules are fetched")
    /* Display results in UI */
  } recoverUI {
    case t: Throwable ⇒
      /* Display error in UI */
  }
}
```

The place where fetchSchedule is called is this:

```
protected override def onResume(): Unit = {
  super.onResume()

  Log.w("Jenastop", "Resume started")

  // Setup timer that refreshes the data every 30
  // seconds.
  timer = new Timer
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask {
    override def run(): Unit = fetchSchedule()
  }, 0, 30000)

  Log.w("Jenastop", "Resume finished")
}
```

Now the problem: Whenever i put the Activity in the background and try to resume it, it freezes until the schedules are fetched. This does not happen when i first start the activity but only when i try to resume it from background.

Log output when resuming from background is this:

```
01-06 11:19:06.694  5280  5280 W Jenastop: Resume started
01-06 11:19:06.694  5280  5280 W Jenastop: Resume finished
01-06 11:19:07.974  5280  5280 I Choreographer: Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-06 11:19:07.974  5280  5280 W Jenastop: Schedules are fetched
/* UI unfreezes */
```

Somehow the UI seems to block until the tasks in THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR are finished. How can i circumvent this?

Comment: A small detail. Instead of `try { promise.successful(...) } catch ... }`, you should simply run `promise.complete(Try(func(value)))`.

Comment: Not an Android expert. So `Schedule.fetch` runs a future, right? Is there a reason that you have to use `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`? In my experience you can easily block futures with custom pools. If you use the default execution context, you can use `blocking { }` in your future bodies where needed to avoid such situations.

Comment: Because Jsoup that you are using inside`Schedule.fetch` is probably blocking. You might be better off with an asynchronous http library. Again, I have very little idea here, but perhaps [this blog](http://blog.ashwanik.in/2015/04/html-parsing-using-jsoup-and-volley-in-android.html) helps doing so.

Comment: The main reason to avoid the scala pool on android is compatibility with some devices. It doesn't always work. http://blog.scaloid.org/2013/11/using-scalaconcurrentfuture-in-android.html

Comment: Jsoup is expected to block. For this reason i run it in a thread pool and not in the UI thread. The UI thread is blocking too though and i can't figure out why.

Comment: There's probably a method to check whether the current thread is the UI thread, like `java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread`. You should at least verify that all your code that runs in non-UI futures does indeed use a dedicated thread.

Comment: Found out it was probably a problem with the emulator. On a real device it works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

The error is somehow related to the emulator. When running the code on a real device the delay is not happening at all.

On the emulator however it seems like the activity only resumes when the thread pool is depleted. I tested that by adding a constant delay to the network connection.

If someone has a better answer to what exactly is happening here I'll be glad to accept it but as it is only an issue during debugging I am not motivated to research it any further